# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module Jest when node modules are ignored

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, es6-modules

Getting `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` while unit testing with Jest. The error is coming from the `node-fetch` package that is [**required**](https://github.com/developit/jsdom-worker/blob/master/package.json#:%7E:text=%22-,node%2Dfetch,-%22%3A%20%22%5E2.6.0%22) by the [`jsdom-worker`](https://github.com/developit/jsdom-worker) package. This could be an issue with the `node-fetch` package but not entirely sure.

I have node modules ignored in my `jest.config.js` so why is this an issue?

`jest.config.js` file:

```
const ignores = ['/node_modules/', '/__fixtures__/', '/fixtures/', '/__tests__/helpers/', '/__tests__/utils/', '__mocks__'];

module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    roots: ['<rootDir>'],
    modulePaths: [
        "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    moduleDirectories: [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    transformIgnorePatterns: [...ignores],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
        '^.+\\.(gif|svg|ico)$': '<rootDir>/svgTransform.js',
    },
    testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.js?$',
    moduleFileExtensions: ['tsx', 'js', 'json', 'node', 'ts'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
      },
    clearMocks: true,
    // collectCoverage: true, // todo
    // coverageDirectory: "coverage",  // todo
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect', 'jsdom-worker'],
}
// }
```

**UPDATE:**
After downgrading `node-fetch` to version 2.4, *that* error went away, but now have the same Syntax issue with another package, why does this keep happening?

**Code Trace**
[image]

`babel.config.js`

```
// Need to convert modules to commonjs format so Jest can undertstand them.
const isTest = String(process.env.NODE_ENV) === 'test'
const isProd = String(process.env.NODE_ENV) === 'production'

module.exports = {
    // For transformation of TSX and other react related bable plugins
    presets: [
        // Allows smart transpilation according to target environments
        ['@babel/preset-env', { modules: isTest ? 'commonjs' : false }],
        // Enabling Babel to understand TypeScript
        '@babel/preset-typescript',
    ],
}
```

Also tried ***[this](https://github.com/kentcdodds/kcd-scripts/blob/main/src/config/babelrc.js)*** babel config from kcd-scripts:

```
"use strict";

const browserslist = require('browserslist');

const semver = require('semver');

const {
  ifDep,
  ifAnyDep,
  ifTypescript,
  parseEnv,
  appDirectory,
  pkg
} = require('../utils');

const {
  BABEL_ENV,
  NODE_ENV,
  BUILD_FORMAT
} = process.env;
const isTest = (BABEL_ENV || NODE_ENV) === 'test';
const isPreact = parseEnv('BUILD_PREACT', false);
const isRollup = parseEnv('BUILD_ROLLUP', false);
const isUMD = BUILD_FORMAT === 'umd';
const isCJS = BUILD_FORMAT === 'cjs';
const isWebpack = parseEnv('BUILD_WEBPACK', false);
const isMinify = parseEnv('BUILD_MINIFY', false);
const treeshake = parseEnv('BUILD_TREESHAKE', isRollup || isWebpack);
const alias = parseEnv('BUILD_ALIAS', isPreact ? {
  react: 'preact'
} : null);
const hasBabelRuntimeDep = Boolean(pkg.dependencies && pkg.dependencies['@babel/runtime']);
const RUNTIME_HELPERS_WARN = 'You should add @babel/runtime as dependency to your package. It will allow reusing "babel helpers" from node_modules rather than bundling their copies into your files.';

if (!treeshake && !hasBabelRuntimeDep && !isTest) {
  throw new Error(RUNTIME_HELPERS_WARN);
} else if (treeshake && !isUMD && !hasBabelRuntimeDep) {
  console.warn(RUNTIME_HELPERS_WARN);
}
/**
 * use the strategy declared by browserslist to load browsers configuration.
 * fallback to the default if don't found custom configuration
 * @see https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist/blob/master/node.js#L139
 */


const browsersConfig = browserslist.loadConfig({
  path: appDirectory
}) || ['defaults'];
const envTargets = isTest ? {
  node: 'current'
} : isWebpack || isRollup ? {
  browsers: browsersConfig
} : {
  node: getNodeVersion(pkg)
};
const envOptions = {
  modules: false,
  loose: true,
  targets: envTargets
};

module.exports = () => ({
  presets: [[require.resolve('@babel/preset-env'), envOptions], ifAnyDep(['react', 'preact'], [require.resolve('@babel/preset-react'), {
    pragma: isPreact ? ifDep('react', 'React.h', 'h') : undefined
  }]), ifTypescript([require.resolve('@babel/preset-typescript')])].filter(Boolean),
  plugins: [[require.resolve('@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'), {
    useESModules: treeshake && !isCJS
  }], require.resolve('babel-plugin-macros'), alias ? [require.resolve('babel-plugin-module-resolver'), {
    root: ['./src'],
    alias
  }] : null, ifAnyDep(['react', 'preact'], [require.resolve('babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types'), isPreact ? {
    removeImport: true
  } : {
    mode: 'unsafe-wrap'
  }]), isUMD ? require.resolve('babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables') : null, [require.resolve('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'), {
    loose: true
  }], isMinify ? require.resolve('babel-plugin-minify-dead-code-elimination') : null, treeshake ? null : require.resolve('@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs')].filter(Boolean)
});

function getNodeVersion({
  engines: {
    node: nodeVersion = '10.13'
  } = {}
}) {
  const oldestVersion = semver.validRange(nodeVersion).replace(/[>=<|]/g, ' ').split(' ').filter(Boolean).sort(semver.compare)[0];

  if (!oldestVersion) {
    throw new Error(`Unable to determine the oldest version in the range in your package.json at engines.node: "${nodeVersion}". Please attempt to make it less ambiguous.`);
  }

  return oldestVersion;
}
```

Comment: can you post your typescript and/or babel configs? the issue is probably there.

Comment: just posted @Derek

Comment: With both babel configs, I got the same error.

Comment: @Derek any thoughts on this?

Comment: The second image shows a browser build being used (`index.browser.js`). JS bundles meant for the browser do not need to adhere to Node's file naming conventions, so it can use `import` in a `.js` file in a non-`"type": "module"` package. However, this does not work in Node. You need to ensure Jest isn't consuming browser bundles as they may not adhere to Node's ESM conventions.

Comment: @rschristian got it -- would you have any idea on how to configure this in Jest?

Comment: On second look, that package (`bigint-conversion`) doesn't export valid ESM in Node. You might need to manually transpile it, assuming the author doesn't want to fix that. Probably will want to open an issue with them.

Comment: Wrote up https://github.com/juanelas/bigint-conversion/issues/10, though that might only fix your immediate issue once a patch is released.

Comment: @rschristian thank you for that. I played around with the config a bit more, installed a package called `jest-webpack-resolver` and that cleaned up that error. Now, I am running into a `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` with a different package

Comment: Welcome to Node ESM. It's still extremely rough so you're better off transpiling your `node_modules` likely.

Comment: @rschristian Yep. I solved the next syntax error I got by downgrading the nanoid package I was using to the next lower version and that fixed it .. keep getting weird stuff like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reconfigured my jest config to this and also needed to mock the packages that were throwing errors which was causing most of the errors:

```
module.exports = {
    roots: ['<rootDir>'],
    modulePaths: ['<rootDir>/src'],
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)?$': 'babel-jest',
        '^.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|ico|url)$':
            '<rootDir>/src/__tests__/__utils__/imageTransform.js',
    },
    testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.js?$',

    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/__utils__/'],
    moduleFileExtensions: ['tsx', 'js', 'ts'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
        '\\.(png|jpg|webp|ttf|woff|woff2|svg|mp4)$':
            '<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
    },
    clearMocks: true,
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [
        '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect',
        './src/__tests__/__utils__/setup.js',
    ],
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.{ts,tsx}', '!src/tests'],
}
```

The mocks were as simple as:

```js
module.exports = {
    nanoid: () =>
        Array(100)
            .fill()
            .map(() => Math.random())
            .join(''),
}
```

for nanoid in a root level `__mocks__` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by installing the package `jest-webpack-resolver` and adding

```
 "jestWebpackResolver": {
        "webpackConfig": "./webpack.config.js"
    },
```

to my `package.json`.

Comment: Why does this solve it though?

Comment: Ah, this post needs to be updated.

Comment: Hi Anthony, I'm struggling with similar problems currently. I tried so many thing. Stumbled upon your 'Question' here and wondering if I should try jestWebpackResolver, although I'm using ts/webpack, no Babel.? But I'm a little bit in doubt what really solved it for you as you seem to have two solutions here, one from oct and one from july. Is it possible you could indicate what really solved it in your case. Is jestWebpackResolver necessary?